# How can i get link from MSO code via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have lots of links in my code. I got all links from code but which links are presented in the `MSO` code I didn't get those links. In `MSO` code there is no `<a>` tag that's why it's hard for me to select the link. I have tried with `document.querySelectorAll("[href]");`. It's not working. Can anyone please help me here that how can I get links from `MSO` code

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll("[href]");

for(let link of links)
{
  let curhref = link.href;
  if(curhref.indexOf('http') > -1)
  {
    link.href = curhref.replace(/(\?|&)elqTrackId=[a-z0-9]+(&elqTrack=true)?/, '');
    if(link.href.indexOf('ea=') > -1)
    {
      link.href += '&utm_source=iconnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&emailId={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&codsId={{Account.CODS_External_Id__c}}&utm_term=';
    }
    else
    {
      link.href += '?utm_source=iconnect&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&emailId={{Approved_Document_vod__c.Vault_Document_ID_vod__c}}&codsId={{Account.CODS_External_Id__c}}&utm_term=';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<body width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #f4f4f4; width: 100% !important;">
  <center style="width: 100% !important; background-color: #f4f4f4;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#f4f4f4" style="width:100% !important;">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="">
          <table class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <!-- TEXT HEADER SECTION STARTS -->
            <tbody>

              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; border-collapse: collapse; color: #717171; font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-smoothing: antialiased; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding: 10px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; word-spacing: 2px; border: 2px solid #4089c3;">
                  <a href="https://www.google.com/dummy0?ea=8mYoHZtET8c&elqTrackId=a3a008f9213248fe8bb899351706a6ad">Lorem Ipsum</a> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the <a href="mailto:dummy@gmail.com">industry's</a> standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type <a href="tel:012414 258">and</a> scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into <a href="http://www.google.com/dummy1?elqTrackId=2cdd5998b5024a23b2d21839786d24a8&elqTrack=true">electronic</a> typesetting, <a href="http://www.google.com/dummy2&elqTrackId=2cdd5998b5024a23b2d21839786d24a8&elqTrack=true">remaining</a> essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently <a href="http://www.google.com/dumm3">with</a> desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
        <td align="center" style="border-radius: 2px;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 15px" class="space-change">
           <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#449E9A" align="center" class="" style="line-height: normal; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
                      xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
                      href="http://images.inform.janssen-emea.com/Web/JanssenPharmaceutica/{fa93572c-25a0-491c-bdd6-b777323d4b2f}_The_Clayton_Hotel__Limerick.ics"
                      style="height:40px; v-text-anchor:middle; width:262px; font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; line-height: 39px;"
                      stroke="f" fillcolor="#449E9A">
                      <w:anchorlock/>
                      <center>
                    <![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://images.inform.janssen-emea.com/Web/JanssenPharmaceutica/{fa93572c-25a0-491c-bdd6-b777323d4b2f}_The_Clayton_Hotel__Limerick.ics?elqTrackId=48cc95382bb74867af4281dff7ffa583" target="_blank" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Verdana',Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; width: 262px; height: 40px; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 39px;" class="mobile-button mobile-width">
                      ADD TO CALENDAR
                    </a>
                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </center>
                    </v:rect>
                    <![endif]-->
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
  </center>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean the bits inside `<!--[if mso]` ... `[endif]-->` ?

In HTML, `<!--` starts a [comment block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment).

And `-->` ends a comment block.

Anything within those tags is considered a comment, and is not part of the DOM, so JavaScript cannot see it.

Some extra background: The `<!--[if mso]` ... `[endif]-->` syntax is Microsoft-specific code called a [conditional comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537512(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Microsoft applications which render HTML (including Internet Explorer and Outlook) may read these and interpret them as code, and then, if the condition is met, will render the content between those blocks into the DOM. To all other browsers/renderers though, they are meaningless apart from the standard comment tags, and so are treated just as comments. Even in Microsoft apps, conditional comments are now something of a legacy feature, less and less necessary as the rendering engines gain better support for web standards.

In this case the `mso` refers to Microsoft Outlook, so this content will only be rendered if the HTML is being viewed in Outlook.